# NodeJS: Problem with testing if IP is reachable

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, ping

## Check if IP is reachable using NodeJS

#### Context:

I'm currently working on a CLI Tools for the company i'm working for. Including a automated testing tool if some of the IP's are reachable via ICMP Ping (IPv4 only)
For this task, i'm using the NPM Package [`ping`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ping) to test each IP async.

#### Question

My Problem is, every test results in true, even if the IP isn't even in the same Subnet.
What am i doing wrong?...

#### Code

There are some methods for gathering Input from the User and Validating:

```js
async function GetIpAddresses(): Promise<IpAddressList> {} // Get Input from User in various Menues
async function ValidateIPAddress(IpAddress: string): Promise<boolean> {} // Validate IPv4 Format
```

Main Method

```js
function main(): void {
    // Get IP Addresses from User
    GetIpAddresses().then(async (result: IpAddressList) => {
        // Validate IP Addresses inputed by User and perform a single Ping
        result.AdressList.forEach(async (IpAddress) => {
        // Validate
        await ValidateIPAddress(IpAddress).then(async (isValid) => {
            if (isValid) {
                // IP Address is valid
                WriteInfo(`IP-Address: ${IpAddress} is valid`);
                await ping.promise.probe(IpAddress).then(async (isAlive) => {
                    if (isAlive) {
                        WriteSuccess(`IP-Address: ${IpAddress} is alive!`);
                    } else {
                        WriteError(`IP-Address: ${IpAddress} is dead!`);
                    }
                });
            } else {
                // IP Address is invalid
                WriteWarning(`IP-Address: ${IpAddress} is invalid!`);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

What am i doing wrong?
I suspected that there may be something wrong with my handling of promises/async. But i couldn't figure out what.

Please note that i'm no full time developer. I'm Sysadmin. Don't expect no wonders.

Thanks for any Help.

Comment: On the top of the problem, I would not use then and async together. You could refactor it.

Comment: Instead of e.g. `await ValidateIPAddress(IpAddress).then(async (isValid) => {...})` you'd write `const isValid = await ValidateIPAddress(IpAddress)`

Comment: I bet the `dead` IPs are in the `.catch()` that's missing here

Comment: But regardless of this, I'm not sure what you mean by every test being true - you mean you get "IP address is alive"? Did you confirm with a manual `ping` that the given IP isn't actually alive?

Comment: thanks for the advice with async/then, goes on my list for code cleaning. 
With "every testing being true" i mean that, even if i can confirm with a manual ping that some ip isn't reachable, the result of the code is still true. Every Time.

Answer (score 2):

thanks for your Support. I found the answer myself.

This method:

```js
await ping.promise
.probe(IpAddress)
.then(async (isAlive) => {
        if (isAlive) {
            WriteSuccess(`IP-Address: ${IpAddress} is alive!`);
        } else {
            WriteError(`IP-Address: ${IpAddress} is dead!`);
        }
    })
.catch(() => {
    WriteError(`IP-Address: ${IpAddress} is dead!`);
});
```

actually returns a more complex response than just a boolean (true/false):

```js
{
  inputHost: '192.168.1.1',
  host: '192.168.1.1',
  alive: false,
  output: '\r\n' +
    'Ping wird ausgef�hrt f�r 192.168.1.1 mit 32 Bytes Daten:\r\n' +
    'Zeit�berschreitung der Anforderung.\r\n' +
    '\r\n' +
    'Ping-Statistik f�r 192.168.1.1:\r\n' +
    '    Pakete: Gesendet = 1, Empfangen = 0, Verloren = 1\r\n' +
    '    (100% Verlust),\r\n',
  time: 'unknown',
  times: [],
  min: 'unknown',
  max: 'unknown',
  avg: 'unknown',
  stddev: 'unknown',
  packetLoss: '100.000',
  numeric_host: '192.168.1.1'
}
```

#### Solution

```js
await ping.promise.probe(IpAddress)
.then(async (pingResult) => {
    if (pingResult.alive) {
        WriteSuccess(`IP-Address: ${IpAddress} is alive!`);
    } else {
        WriteError(`IP-Address: ${IpAddress} is dead!`);
    }
})
.catch(() => {
    WriteError(`IP-Address: ${IpAddress} is dead!`);
});
```

#### Note

Once this project is finished, i'm giving you guys a Link to my GL Repo. This ain't any proprietary code so that's not a Problem. Maybe someone could use this.

Comment: Great that you found the solution! I cleaned up the code a bit for you so that you can learn how to use `async`/`await` correctly: https://gist.github.com/CherryDT/a5e86751d8864dce708c3eeade45d16a

Comment: Suggestion: You could also run all the pings in parallel instead of doing it sequentially - will be faster overall, especially if there are many hosts which are _not_ reachable: https://gist.github.com/CherryDT/49a5ad5a14c04fe382f44399a9fa839c